# Use std::bind return object and placeholder as argument in another function

Tags: c++

I would like to forward a function object from std::bind to another function but use the placeholder only in the final called function.

I have an external class that can't be modified. It has functions I would like to use in member functions of another class. All functions in this class must pass through a filter (function `b`). Function b has special double values that are used for all member functions, and I'd prefer not to use a global.

I want to do something where I can create member class functions, and then send those member class functions to the filter function `b`, but have the placeholder used only in function `b`.

For example, function `fn` has a placeholder in the bind, but I want to send `fn` to function `b` and have function `b` use `n` as the value for the placeholder in `fn`.

```
double ExtClass::a(int x, double y, double z)
{
     //do stuff
     return val;
}

double Class::b(std::function<void(double)> f)
{
    //do stuff
    double n = 7.88982;
    double res = f(n);
    return res;
}

double Class::c()
{
    //do some stuff...
    auto fn = std::bind(ExtClass::a, 2, 2.85, std::placeholders::_1);
    //I want to do something like this
    double res = b(fn(std::placeholders::_1));
    return res;
}
```

This code doesn't compile, seemingly due to the fact that function `c` technically invokes the function with the placeholder, which doesn't work. How do I resolve this? The additional arguments passed to the bind are calculated in function `c`.

Comment: What's wrong with `b(fn)`?

Comment: Two things: A pointer to a member function *must* use the address-of operator `&`. As in `&ExtClass::a`. Secondly, if `a` is a non-static member function then you need an *object* to call it on. Which is passed as the first argument.

Comment: Use a lambda if you have C++11.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Use of `std::placeholders` and `std::bind` indicates they *do* have C++11.

Comment: @Angew There were already available in C++03.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Nope. C++03 had `std::bind1st` etc., but placeholders and `std::bind` are a C++11 thing. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). (I know a wiki is not proof, but I don't know how to link to a C++03 standard).

Comment: @Angew Oh.. confused with Boost, indeed...

Comment: @T.C. using `b(fn)` gives a type mismatch because `fn` gets converted to a `std::_Binder` object at some point

Comment: Another thing: The arguments used in the `bind` call should match the actual function!

Comment: Is `ExtClass::a` static? Otherwise, your call is missing an object of type `ExtClass`.

Comment: @Angew Well, if not, it's also missing a `bitand` to form a pointer to member.

Comment: @Shan Why type mismatch? `std::function` can be created from the result of a `std::bind` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) [suggested in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127417/use-stdbind-return-object-and-placeholder-as-argument-in-another-function/54127518#comment95086081_54127417), the solution is in fact very simple. `fn` is already a callable which accepts one `double`, so just use it as such:

```
double res = b(fn);
```

Why this works: placeholders are required when creating a bind expression to express the idea "this argument will be provided later." The result of that bind expression is a callable whose parameters are determined by the placeholders used in the bind expression. After this, it can be used just like any other callable.

Note that your code has an error in the signature of `b`: you've declared `f` with a `void` return type, but you're treating it as if it was returning `double`. The signature of `b` should be

```
double Class::b(std::function<double(double)> f)
```

With this change, the code works. [[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3924cab6554a4ae1)